# Vue add new items to array of an object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component, vue-reactivity

I have an array like this:

```
campaigns = [
    {id: 1, adGroups: [{id: 1, title: 'Hello'}, {id: 2, title: 'Hello'}]},
    {id: 2, adGroups: [{id: 3, title: 'Hello'}, {id: 4, title: 'Hello'}]},
];
```

I render the array using `v-for`:

```
<fieldset class="mb-3 p-3 rounded border" v-for="(campaign, index) in campaigns" :key="index">
    <fieldset class="mb-3 p-3 rounded border" v-for="(campaignAdGroup, indexAdGroup) in campaign.adGroups" :key="indexAdGroup">
        {{ campaignAdGroup.title }}
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

It's fine, but now I want to add a new item to the `campaign.adGroups`, but it seems it doesn't work.

I have used the `$set` function to add new items to the array but it doesn't work.

```
this.$set(this.ruleCampaigns[index].adGroups, this.ruleCampaigns[index].adGroups.length, {id: null, title: ''})
```

How can I handle this case in VUE?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `this.ruleCampaigns[index].adGroups.push({id: null, data: {bid: ''}})`?

Comment: @LucasMarcondesPavelski Yes, I have tried but doesn't work as well.

Comment: @shob When I add new item, the UI should display one more element, but it doesn't.

Comment: @shob Yes, it doesn't display the added item.

Comment: Yeah, That's sample code only, I just changed the question. Tks

Comment: Should work. How do you call the method? Are you sure `index` is not `undefined`? If you are calling the method outside of the loop then you don't have access to `index`.

Comment: How did you define/use campaigns on the model? Is it an observable?

Comment: @BroiSatse

I have a parent component, the component will include the child component that I posted in the question. I passed a prop called "submitData".

On the data function of the child component:

data() {
    let postData = this.submitData

    if (!postData.campaigns) {
      postData.campaigns = [{id: null, title: ''}]
    }

    return {
      campaigns: postData.campaigns
    }
  }

Comment: Finally, I found the issue, the issue happens because I didn't assign the adGroups property for the origin object, I assigned the adGroups property after the UI rendered.

Comment: Then your question was not correct. That is why you should always try to reproduce the bug. You would have found it much faster.

Comment: @AdamOrlov Because my code is pretty complex, I cannot add full the code to the question, so I prepared what similar with my code. But unfortunately it doesn't fit with this case :)

Answer (score 2):

When adding an element to an array, `$set` isn't needed, you can use the `.push` method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      campaigns: [
        {id: 1, adGroups: [{id: 1, title: 'Hello'}, {id: 2, title: 'Hello'}]},
        {id: 2, adGroups: [{id: 3, title: 'Hello'}, {id: 4, title: 'Hello'}]},
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    add(index) {
      const campaign = this.campaigns[index];
      const groups = campaign.adGroups;
      groups.push({ id: groups.length + 1, title: 'Hello' });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <fieldset class="mb-3 p-3 rounded border" v-for="(campaign, index) in campaigns" :key="index">
    <fieldset class="mb-3 p-3 rounded border" v-for="(campaignAdGroup, indexAdGroup) in campaign.adGroups" :key="indexAdGroup">
      {{ campaignAdGroup.title }}
    </fieldset>
    <button @click="add(index)">Add</button>
  </fieldset>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```